# Android app crashes without error while switching from activity_main layout to content_main layout

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has two activities: `MainActivity` and `OnlineActivity`. The code snippet of `onCreate` method of `MainActivity.java` is:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button btnOnline = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Online);
        if (btnOnline != null){
            btnOnline.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     online();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The `online` method inside `MainActivity.java` is defined as follows:

```
 private void online() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext:MainActivity.this, OnlineActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Similarly, code snippet of `onCreate` method of `OnlineActivity.java` is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);}
```

The `activity_main.xml` has a button (button id is *Online*) and the `content_main.xml` has a simple text view.

While running the app, the button is displayed first, while pressing on the button the app crashes without any error (next view is not displayed).

The Logcat (Verbose) is as follows:

[image]

After crashing, the displayed message is ***My_App keeps stopping***. And I get ***App info*** and ***Close app*** options.

What could have gone wrong in my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add *stack-trace* to your question?

Comment: Have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for getting (and interpreting) the stack trace.

Comment: The Logcat screen capture doesn't show the crash. And text is preferred over images. Was `OnlineActivity` added to the manifest file?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen `onlineActivity` is on the manifest file.

Comment: @santobedi Can you please add  try and catch block on Button Click Method

Comment: Make sure you add "OnlineActivity" into AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MainActivity.java` Please change the inside `online` method:

```
 private void online() {
  try{
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,OnlineActivity.class));

     }
  catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code snippets provided, I don't see any reason why the app should crash.
Just for the sanity check, please compare the below snippet with yours:
NOTE: **below code runs without crash** and the ToolBar isn't necessary if you aren't using those. I hope this helps.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private AppCompatButton onlineButton;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    onlineButton = findViewById(R.id.Online);

    setOnlineClickListener()`enter code here`;
  }

  private void setOnlineClickListener() {

    onlineButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent onlineIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OnlineActivity.class);
        startActivity(onlineIntent);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
      >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/Online"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello World!"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
      />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

OnlineActivity.java

```
    public class OnlineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_online);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }
}
```

activity_online.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OnlineActivity"
    >

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
      >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="This is Online Activity"
      />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.foo">

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".OnlineActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_online"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```